# JavaScript global scope

Tags: javascript

I ran this code in my console but got undefined. However I expected it to return `1` because function 2 returns a, which is a var in the global scope.

Can you please explain where I'm mistaken? thank you.

```
var a = 1;
function f1() {var a = 1; f2();}
function f2() {return a;}
f1();
```

Comment: To change the global variable itself, just omit the `var` e.g. `function f1() { a = 1; }` otherwise by having `var` you create brand new local variable that is not affecting the global one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with the return value of `f2`.  You'd need to do this:

```
var a = 1;
function f1() {var a = 1; return f2();} // NB pass the return value on
function f2() {return a;}
f1();
```

Comment: Also, `var a = 1;` inside of `f1` is redundant.

Comment: i didn't think it necessary to return f2 inside f1 because f1 invoked f2.

Comment: I assumed that was the case, just thought it'd be good for clarification.

Comment: @Michael You are calling `f2`, which basically means you get the value returned by `f2`.  What you do with that value is up to you. Calling a function doesn't "include" that other function's code within your current function.